# Arrow positioning on a line and above all divs

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm at my wits end with this one.

I have a couple of divs. They all have a downward pointing arrow. It should be centered in the middle, on the brown line and on top of everything. The last div should also have the arrow. I tried z-index, absolute & relative positioning and nothing works.

If you click the title, the box opens. The arrow should stay on the line in the exact spot. This really doesn't seem all that difficult to me, but somehow I can't make it work.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8eLwr

```
<article id="made" data-magellan-destination="made">


<div class="blocks-holder wide made">
    <div class="block wide" id="">
        <div class="openblock">
            <div class="maak-competences">
                 <h2>title</h2>

                 <h4>tagline</h4>

                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </div>
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: it would be better next time to put just ***enough*** code into your demo so that editing will be easier.

Comment: Agree, this is someone else's HTML & CSS. I would have taken a different approach, but I have to work with what I've got. There is also another collapsible block in the HTML and the code must work together. Thanks for taking the time, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the absolute positioning from the arrow and instead set it to display as `block` and give it `margin: 0 auto` to centralise it:

```css
.arrow-down {
    ...    
    background-position: bottom;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto -36px auto;    
}
```

*Note that I've also set its `background-position` to `bottom` to make the background image sit directly at the bottom of the element.*

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eLwr/5/).

**Edit:** from comments:

> Yes, it should be just underneath the brown line, so it sort of looks like this: -----v------- The two point of the V should touch the line

This is a bit of a large change. We need to remove the background from the individual blocks (to stop them overlapping the arrow), then remove the float from the block container (to fix the height), then finally give the container the white background and increase the negative margin on the arrow:

```css
.blocks-holder .block {
    ...
    float: left; /* Remove this. */
}

.blocks-holder .block.wide {
    ...
    background: transparent;
}

.blocks-holder.wide {
    ...
    background: #fff;
}

.arrow-down {
    ...
    margin: 0 auto -46px auto;    
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eLwr/7/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer, but the arrow should be on the brown line :)

Comment: @user2970137 please see my edit. Do you want it to touch the brown line?

Comment: Yes, it should be just underneath the brown line, so it sort of looks like this:


-----v-------

The two point of the V should touch the line so it is smooth like the other arrow (in the content box on the lower right side)
I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much & for taking the time to help me.